# Minikube not starting on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, kubernetes, minikube

I'm just getting started with kuberneted on Windows 10.
I downloaded the bits from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases).

While attempting to start minikube from powershell:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv
```

I'm encountering the error:

```
Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E1202 06:53:29.869106    2368 start.go:150] Error starting host: Error starting stopped host: exit status 1.
```

While the documentation does not mention any prerequisites to run minikube, is there any setting on Windows 10 that needs to change to make it run?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 9):

While I do not completely understand what happend, I chanced upon [this article](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1400).

---

I got minikube running using the following steps:

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube delete 
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl config use-context minikube
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv
```

Comment: I am conviced, that `minikube delete` did something right. I have no idea what this might be.

Comment: I have different problem. My problem is after I run this command: "minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv". It show below info: "Starting local Kubernetes v1.13.2 cluster...
Starting VM...
Skipping hyperv driver, existing host has virtualbox driver.
E0129 11:16:30.514075   15932 start.go:205] Error starting host: Error starting stopped host: Unable to start the VM: D:
\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm minikube --type headless failed:" After executing above command minikube start normally.

Answer (score 4):

Let say your `minicube` is installed on `X:` drive and your profile is on `Y:` drive. Then, to start the minikube you have to run the following two commands at the console:

```
Y:
X:\path-to-minicube\minikube.exe start
```

So, first command should position you on the profile drive (as minikube stores its files there and then tries to access them with **no any mention** of the drive, just starting with `/`). And second one is just running the EXE with correct "current drive".

P.S. And in case your minikube still complains it can't start stopped service, just run `minikube delete` (because this software is stateful) and try that two commands again.

Answer (score 2):

Incomplete or wrong installation lead this issue.There are some files, settings are cached. Deleting those might solve the problem. There is a folder called .minikube . It could be in profile folder or where minikube binary located. Delete that one and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Start the command prompt with administrator privileges.

Right click  on the cmd.exe icon and choose Runs As Administrator

Answer (score 1):

Might be because an existing old setup files are still residing.
Just a proper cleanup minikube worked for me

```
$ minikube delete
Deleting local Kubernetes cluster...
Machine deleted.
```